# how to search values in column and make them as columns using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

```
select 
     distinct state,sector,
             pt.RSGHDPE as [PPC],pt.OPC43HDPE as [OPC43],
             pt.OPC53HDPE as [OPC53],pt.RSFHDPE as [RSF]
from RMCL_DESPSUM_This_year as t
pivot (min(t.factory) for t.item_name in( RSGHDPE,OPC53HDPE,OPC43HDPE,RSFHDPE)) as pt
where inv_Date between'2017-04-01 00:00:00.000'and getdate()
order by state
```

I have given one value from item code which is RSGHDPE , but i have 6 items which starts with RSG likewise for other itemnames also

what i am looking for is below one or any other method

```
pivot (min(t.factory) for t.item_name like( 'RSG%','OPC53%','OPC43%','RSF%')) as pt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: @BhatiaAshish i did'nt find any column name to search in that link and i have some 250 values in column i need only some values to be rows

Comment: Find your columns list first and use it in a dynamic sql

Comment: i am very new to sql server can u explain me clearly @plaidDK

Comment: You need to declare a variable which holds the list of the columns you want in your pivot. This will be a much better solution since you can isolate which columns you actually want to target. Look for dynamic pivot examples. There  is a lot. Just like @BhatiaAshish writes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for few `item_names` then you could use some conditional aggregation approach.

```
SELECT  
        state, sector,
        MIN(CASE WHEN item_name LIKE 'RSG%' THEN factory END) PPC,
        ...
        MIN(CASE WHEN item_name LIKE 'RSF%' THEN factory END) RSF
FROM RMCL_DESPSUM_This_year as t
WHERE inv_Date between @start AND @end
GROUP BY state,sector
```